# Must eval be a string or code object?

Tags: python, eval, command-line-arguments

When I run the code below, I get the following error:  eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object

Anyone know why? This is code i'm learning from a book, so I assumed that it would be correct.

```
 # Prompt the user to enter three numbers
number1 = eval(input("Enter the first number: "))
number2 = eval(input("Enter the second number: "))
number3 = eval(input("Enter the third number: "))

 # Compute average
average = (number1 + number2 + number3) / 3

print("The average of", number1, number2, number3, "is", average)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `input()` on Python 2, which *already* runs `eval()` on the input. Just remove the `eval()` call, or replace `input()` with `raw_input()`.

Alternatively, use Python 3 to run this code, it is clearly aimed at that version. If your book uses this syntax, then you want to use the right version to run the code samples.

Most of all, don't use `input()` on Python 2 or `eval()` on Python 3. If you want integer numbers, use `int()` instead.

Python 2 example:

```
# Prompt the user to enter three numbers
number1 = int(raw_input("Enter the first number: "))
number2 = int(raw_input("Enter the second number: "))
number3 = int(raw_input("Enter the third number: "))

# Compute average
average = (number1 + number2 + number3) / 3

print "The average of", number1, number2, number3, "is", average
```

Python 3 version:

```
# Prompt the user to enter three numbers
number1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
number2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
number3 = int(input("Enter the third number: "))

# Compute average
average = (number1 + number2 + number3) / 3

print("The average of", number1, number2, number3, "is", average)
```

Comment: Hey, I came across this post, why shouldn't we use `eval` in Python 3.x and why is `print(eval(input()))` not working in Python 2.7 but `print(eval(raw_input()))` is?

Comment: @0x45: see [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1832940) and [What's the difference between raw\_input() and input() in python3.x?](//stackoverflow.com/q/4915361)